# How to do nothing in ternary else part?

Tags: jquery, conditional-operator

I have this line on my js code:

```
('lr' in p) ? $(element).html(p.lr) : 0;
```

`p` is a JSON object. When I minify with Google closure, I get a suspicious code error

Comment: What do you mean by *return null action*? Surely replacing the `0` with `null` will suffice?

Comment: Suspicious code error again..

Comment: You don't seem to be doing anything with the value returned from the ternary, so it seems a little redundant anyway: `if ('lr' in p) $(element).html(p.lr);`: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/ga7yxe18/

Comment: why ternary, can't you just use an if? as I see you don't return anything.

Comment: I mean null action for do nothing

Comment: If you don't want to do anything in the 'else' part of a ternary, then don't use a ternary. A plain `if` condition works, as per my previous comment.

Comment: Also note that I'm assuming that `p` is an object, not a JSON string. There's no such thing as a 'JSON object'

Comment: I wouldn't want to use if, just to know if i can do nothing in ternary else part

Comment: No, you have to do *something*, but this is why you're getting the warning from Google - because you're mis-using a ternary. It could also be for your use of `in` against an object.

Comment: Because you're not actually *using* a `ternary else part` so it's suspicious that you have it in your code.   In your own words, you want to do "if this do that else do nothing" which is the same as "if this do that" (with no else (as confirmed above in the comments)) which is not a ternary condition, so it's warning you that you're trying to do something that doesn't make sense and should probably be doing something else.

Comment: Okay, guys. I take note.

Comment: if i keep this line as that, its dangerous?

Comment: It does nothing, so shouldn't be a problem, but I'm not familiar enough with Google Closure.  Is it an error (so no code generated) or a warning (so just letting you know)?  If it's just a warning and the code is still being mini-fied, then a you should be able to run your tests against it to see if it still works as expected and move on.

Comment: Yes, it work well as expected after i mini-fied the code. Thanks for all.